# Prime Numbers and Infinity

Tags: prime-numbers, natural-numbers

*Forgive me if this comes off as gross abuse of maths, but it made me curious.*

As the sequence of natural numbers is infinite, this would also mean there should be an infinite number of primes. However, if the distance between primes continues to grow between each new prime found, would this not mean that there would be an infinite gap between primes due to the sequence of natural numbers being infinite, meaning that there aren't an infinite number of primes?

Comment: The fact that there are infinitely many natural numbers does not immediately tell you that there infinitely many primes.  Nor is there necessarily a problem with "increasing gaps".   For example, there are infinitely many perfect squares and the gaps between them grows to infinity.

Comment: "an infinite gap between primes" ? In what sense: the "distance" between two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ whatever, assuming that $p_1 < p_2$ will be $p_2 - p_1$ that is a *finite* number.

Comment: It is not easy to "measure" *infinity*: an infinite set can have an infinite **proper** subset: consider e.g. the set of natural numbers and its proper subset of *even* numbers.

Comment: This might help, or it might not: if you want a prime number that is greater than some number $x$, that prime always exists no matter how large $x$ is. And if you want a prime gap of at least length $x$, that gap also exists no matter how large $x$ is.

Comment: You're kind of half right. What it means is that there's no upper bound on the distance between consecutive primes.  Although "infinitely many natural numbers" doesn't mean "infinitely many primes" *per se* as you can make infinitely many composite numbers out of finitely many primes.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of primes, which might be difficult to visulaize and argue about, try out how well your argument holds with all the numbers consisting of a single $1$ and trailing zeroes: $1, 10, 100, 1000,\ldots$ You will see that yes, the gaps are growing endlessly (the gaps are, in order, $9, 90, 900,\ldots$), but that doesn't mean that there is a single infinite gap. Also, there are clearly infinitely many of these numbers, since for each natural number, this sequence has an entry with that many zeroes in it.

The same thing happens with primes. The distance from one prime to the next will grow (at least on average; we know that no matter how far out you go on the number line, there will still be small gaps around, but they get rare). That doesn't mean that there is an infinite gap anywhere. And it doesn't mean there are finitely many primes.

Comment: @Azxdreuwa The gaps _do_ tend to infinity (or, at least, there are always larger gaps). That doesn't mean that there ever is a single one which is infinite.

Comment: @Azxdreuwa That is not what "tending to infinity" really means. It just means "grows beyond any bound".